Can't run in release with profile dev? How do I remove profile dev?
In my RustRover run configuration I have
run --release --example=render -- -i  scenes/devoir2/04_test-checkerboards.json

However, when I click run, the actual command being ran is
cargo build --color=always --message-format=json-diagnostic-rendered-ansi --profile dev --release --example=render ...

Naturally, this leads to

error: the argument '--profile ' cannot be used with '--release'

How can I avoid it being ran with --profile dev?

The way to avoid this problem is to remove the --release from your run configuration (or delete the run configuration with --release if you have separate ones for dev builds and release builds, as I had) and instead use the profile selection dropdown to switch between dev and release.

I had just never noticed that there was a drop down! Perhaps you could augment your answer with a screenshot of where that drop down is
